# No Suitable Method Found

Tags: java

This is the method im trying to invoke.

```
    public void update(int status) {
        if (status == 1)
        {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, BORDERSIZE+1));
        }
        else if (status == 2)
        {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, BORDERSIZE+1));
        }
        else if (status == 3)
        {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, BORDERSIZE));
        }

        revalidate();
    }
```

This is the code trying to use it.

```
private void handleMouseClick(int x, int y, int button) {
    try {
        // This is called by the board squares when they are clicked
        // Handle the logic of updates to the client/game here

        if(button == 1){
            if(x != -1 && y != -1){
                update(1);
                x = -1;
                y = -1;
                updateGrids();
                }
            else{
                update(3);
            }
        }
        else if(button == 3){

        }


    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
```

The update method is inside a class called GridLayout, I've tried to just simply use GridLayout.update(aninteger); but it didn't work for me.

Comment: GridLayout.update(aninteger); would only work if the update method is static. Or do you mean new GridLayout.update(aninteger)?

Comment: What im doing is I have a lot of panels and when one is clicked I fire a mouse event to let me know where, the update method just changes the border color of the panel that was clicked.

Comment: `The update method is inside a class called GridLayout`: then create an instance of the class and invoke update on that instance. the only time you can call a function without reference if you are calling it from it's own class context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of GridLayout object in order to call the update function.

Withouth knowning how GridLayout is related to your existing code I cannot advice further. However if GridLayout is a temporary object you could try:

```
GridLayout worker = new GridLayout(... whatever ...);
worker.update(aninteger);
```

Otherwise, you might need to get it from the framework involved, or something along these lines:

```
this.getGridLayout().update(aninteger);
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that it should be the *right* instance; just creating an instance and invoking a method on it will make the compiler happy but most probably not having the desired effect. I guess, the questioner wants to modify an *existing* instance.

Comment: Fair enough but not much information was given. The main point is that an instance of GridLayout is needed.

Comment: That’s right. You can’t tell more than your current answer does.